# Difference between two structure definitions in C

Tags: c

I'd like to understand the difference between two ways of structure definitions in C. If I create a structure like this:

```
struct Node{
    float Point[DIM];
    struct kdNode *left, *right;
};
```

Is it different from:

```
struct Node{
    float Point[DIM];
    struct kdNode *left, *right;
}Node;
```

Where I add the structure name before semicolon.

Comment: None is a _structure **definition**_

Comment: @Olaf please explain. imho both are definitions

Comment: Don't confuse common language with special terms. _definition_ is well defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 5):

The second defines a *variable* named `Node`.

It's equivalent to

```
struct Node{
    float Point[DIM];
    struct kdNode *left, *right;
};

struct Node Node;
```

The definition of the actual structure is the same in both cases. The only difference is the variable definition in the second case.

It should be noted that structure tag names (the first `Node` directly after the `struct` keyword) is in a separate *namespace* which is why it is possible to have a variable with the same name as the structure.

It should also be noted that if you have the variable definition in a header file, and include the header file in more than one source file, then you will have multiple definitions of the variable, and will get an error when linking.

Comment: "The second defines a variable named Node." - Not neccessarily!

Comment: Thank you very much .. If I add `typedef`, does it mean I can use the structure as a type?

Comment: @Olaf please clarify. when does it not?

Comment: @PedroKali Yes, that changes things quite considerable. Instead of defining a variable you defined a *type alias*, where you can use `Node` as a type instead of `struct Node`.

Comment: @Olaf; Interesting! Enlighten us?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: At file level it is just a dexlaration and a _tentative definition_. Wheter it is a normal _definition_ depends on context.

Comment: please bear with me if my understanding of "variable" or "definition" is not inline with the C standard. it this a trick with tentative definitions?

Comment: @Olaf OK, but then i can just say it is not even the declaration of a struct, because that depends on context aswell. For example if I said `struct Node { int x; };` before it, it would just be an invalid construct because `struct Node` was already declared.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The standard is pretty clear about what constitutes a _definition_ and what is just a _declaration_ or a _tentative definition_. This is not about variables (a term which is used without definition). Strictly speaking, there are no _structure (type) definitions_, but only _struct (and union) specifiers_. But that might indeed lead too far here.

Comment: Haha, points taken nevertheless. C never fails to surprises me in terms of how you can play with the terms.

Comment: @Olaf yeah I'm aware of that difference, including that tags have no linkage across TUs, hence the need for type compatibility notions etc.. all different and much simplier in C++.

Comment: It's not about "playing with the terms", but using them correctly. It's the same idea like stack overflow using English language only: to be understood.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb `struct`, `union` and `enum` tags never have linkage; they are no objects. But that is not related here. I strongly doubt it is easier in C++! But much the same, plus templates and symbolic constants (there might be more).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127563/discussion-between-olaf-and-johannes-schaub-litb).

Answer (score 2):

The first case is pretty dull: not too much to say there.

In the second case, `Node` is *also* an *instance* of the `struct Node`.

With a small change,

```
typedef struct Node{
    float Point[DIM];
    struct kdNode *left, *right;
} Node;
```

you achieve something that's idiomatic in C, namely the injection of the `struct` into your `typedef` namespace means you don't need to write `struct Node` when you want to refer to this type.

Answer (score 0):

The second one also defines `struct Node Node`. So `Node.Point[0]` is valid while `struct Node` itself is a type too.

Usually the second one is used to create anonymous structs if you know you only need a couple of variables of that type:

```
struct {
    float Point[DIM];
    struct kdNode *left, *right;
}Node;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the second definition of the structure, you are allowed to create only one variable of that structure type, the one that you had declared along with the structure definition.

In this definition,

```
struct Node{
    float Point[DIM];
    struct kdNode *left, *right;
}Node;
```

You cannot declare more variables like this:

```
struct Node Node2,Node3;
```

All the structure variables you want to use in the program needs to be declared along with the structure definition.

So, using the first definition will be a better option.